# Automatic Callbacks on Radio Button Changes in Ajax.Beginform ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have the following block of code in one of my Partial Pages.

Would like to know if the Ajax request can be made on change of the Radio Butto selection.

Thanks in advance.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_QueriesPartial", "Bug",
 new AjaxOptions
 {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 HttpMethod = "GET",
 OnFailure = "searchFailed",
 LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
 UpdateTargetId = "Result",
 }))
 {
    foreach (Query query in @Model.queries) {
        <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButton("UserQuery", query.id, new { onclick = "submitform()" })
            @Html.Label(query.name, query.name)
        </div>

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null,
             new AjaxOptions
             {
                 HttpMethod = "POST",
                 OnSuccess = "JavascriptUpdateMethod(data, target)",
                 Url = Url.Action("ActionAjax", "Controller")
             }, new { id = AjaxFormId }))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("ActionMethodArg", f.Id)
                <div class="radiobutton-inline">
                    @Html.Label("Default", new { style="width: 45px;"})
                    @Html.RadioButton("name", f.Id, trueorfalse,
                                    new { onchange = "$('#AjaxFormId').trigger('submit');" })
                </div>
            }
```